# How to send unprocessed output over linux serial port?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, archlinux

I did everything. I shutoff the bits to disable the output processing in the termios structure, properly set the baud rate and character size and disabled parity, flush the output and input buffers before sending. Even after all this linux serial still doesn't work the way I want it to. Canonical mode is not even on in the first place, everything is raw bytes. Btw I am using arch linux connected to an arduino nano with an usb cable which will receive the bytes from PC and display them on a lcd. When I send a byte from PC, e.g char 'A', it apears to get corrupted during the transmisson process, and arduino displays the corrupted byte. Everytime I send character 'A' it shows ascii value 254 on the lcd which is clearly wrong. How do I solve this problem?

My C code on pc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  int serial_port = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  getchar();    
  struct termios old_tty; 
  struct termios new_tty;   

  if (tcgetattr(serial_port, &new_tty) != 0) {
      printf("Error %i from tcgetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
      return 1;
  }
  
  old_tty = new_tty;              
    
  new_tty.c_cflag &= ~(CSTOPB | CSIZE | PARENB);
  new_tty.c_cflag |= CS8;
  new_tty.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
  new_tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; 
  new_tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY | INPCK | ISTRIP);
  //new_tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;   
  //new_tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

  cfsetispeed(&new_tty, B9600);
  cfsetospeed(&new_tty, B9600);

  if (tcsetattr(serial_port, TCSANOW, &new_tty) != 0) {
      printf("Error %i from tcsetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
      return 1;
  } 
  tcflush(serial_port, TCIOFLUSH);  

  unsigned char val = 'A';
  write(serial_port, &val, sizeof(val));
  getchar();
    
  tcsetattr(serial_port, TCSANOW | TCSADRAIN, &old_tty);
  close(serial_port);
  return 0; 
}
```

Code on Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2); // begins connection to the LCD module
  lcd.backlight(); // turns on the backlight
  lcd.clear(); 
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  lcd.print("Init done"); 
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {    
      uint8_t x = Serial.read(); 
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0); 
      lcd.print("I received: "); 
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1); 
      lcd.print(x); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you're dealing with one too many unknowns at once.  Your program does not check return codes and is uproven.  How do you know that the Arduino side will properly display whatever is received?  How can you be sure that your serial connection is working?  Have you tried to simplify your setup, and test incrementally? First test the serial connection with a terminal emulation program such as **minicom** instead of your code?  Is 'A' the only test you performed?

Comment: The Arduino part of code should works, you can also test your Arduino code by directly typing into the Serial Monitor. So your question is more for Arch Linux. I added the `archlinux` tag for you.

Comment: FWIW your C code for Linux does compile cleanly, and does transmit a single ASCII 'A' character (aka `0x41` in hexadecimal representation) (and ***nothing else***) after typing an `Enter` post startup.  The termios configuration is not thorough. but it is just sufficient to do what you want done.  So that is one less unknown that needs to be tested.  Doesn't seem like the question should be about *sending* from Linux anymore.  Maybe you need to start focusing on the receiving and/or displaying end of your setup.